# Parsing HTML Jsoup - Android

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

Hi guys i have this html page:

> ```
>       client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
>       client.println(F("Content-Type: text/html"));
>       client.println();  
>
>        client.print(F("<html><head><title>ARDUINO Controllo via WEB</title><meta http- v='Content-Type' content='text/html;> charset=iso-8859-1' ></head><body>"));
>
>       client.println(F("<h1><center>Temperatura Attuale: "));
>       client.println(temperature);   
>       client.println(F(" Gradi</h1></center>"));
>
>       //PORTONE CASA
>       client.println(F("<h1>Portone Casa</h1>"));
>       client.print(F("<h2><a href='/?C=30'>APRI</a>"));
>       client.println(F("<hr />"));  
>
>       //GARAGE
>       client.println(F("<h1>Garage</h1>"));
>
>       client.print(F("<h2><a href='/?L=2'>APRI</a>"));
>       client.println(F("<hr />"));  
>
>       //LUCE SCALA
>       client.println(F("<h1>Luce Scala</h1>"));
>
>       client.print(F("<h2><a href='/?L=3'>ACCENDI</a>"));
>
>       client.println(F("</body></html>"));
>
>       readString="";
>       client.stop();
> ```

this page generate with arduino...
this is source code from browser:

> ARDUINO Controllo via WEBmeta
>   http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
>
> > body>h1>center>Temperatura Attuale: 
> >     18.44  Gradih1>center> h1>Portone Casah1> h2>a href='/?C=30'>APRIa>hr /> h1>Garageh1> h2>a href='/?L=2'>APRIa>hr /> h1>Luce Scalah1> h2>a
> >     href='/?L=3'>ACCENDIa>body>html>

How to get 18.44 and set textview on android?
18.44 are C° ...dynamic number...

This is code for my app:

> ```
> //INIZIO private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
> ProgressDialog prog;
> String title = "";
>
> @Override
> protected void onPreExecute() {
>     prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
>     prog.setMessage("Loading....");
>     prog.show();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>     try {
>         org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.1.3").get();
>         Elements tableElement = doc.select("div # temperature");
>       //  title = doc.title();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return title;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
>     super.onPostExecute(result);
>     prog.dismiss();       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> ```

Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap temperature value with

```
<span id="temperature">18.44</span>
```

using this code:

```
client.println(F("<h1><center>Temperatura Attuale: <span id=\"temperature\">"));
client.println(temperature);   
client.println(F("</span> Gradi</h1></center>"));
```

After that you should be able to get a value of this span in your AsyncTask by:

**Edited:**

```
Element span = doc.getElementById("temperature");
String temperature = span.html();
```